# How do I reference an image in JavaScript using the 'src' attribute?

Tags: html, src

I am attempting to display a traffic light image by referencing its source using the 'src' attribute but when ever I try to run it, it just displays the alt heading.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <img src = "Pictures/Computing/Question3Images/red_light1.jpg" alt = "Traffic light 1">

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the little extract of what I have got so far but it is only displaying the alt heading "Traffic light 1". I am new to this coding and so am aware that it is most likely not what it needs to be but can anyone please tell me what I have done wrong or what I need to add.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: There is no JavaScript here. Very likely, the path you are giving `src` is wrong, and the image can't be found. In this event, the browser will display the `alt` text instead.

Comment: describe your forders order near the current file

Answer (score 0):

probably the image does not exists in the path you have defined, thats why the browser displayed the value which is in 'alt' attribute of 'img' tag .